# angular.js factory variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this factory:

```
app.factory('user', function($http) {
    var state; // logged state

    function login(data) {
        $http.post('/login', {..}).success(function(data) {
            this.state = 1;

        });
        console.log(this.state); // undefined
        return this.state;
    }

    return {
        login: login
    }
});
```

When I try to use it inside a controller:

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', function(user) {
    this.login = function() {
        alert(user.login(this.data)); // undefined
    };
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I've got same code in other project and it's working there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in the success callback does not refer to the service. That's why you got an `undefined`, besides the fact that the `console.log` is outside the callback.

You should have better results if you *cache* `this` at the beginning of the service:

```
var service = this;
```

And in the callback, store `state` in `service`:

```
service.state = 1;
```

Comment: tried, but also not working because I should use promises

Comment: Indeed, `login` should return the `$http` promise, and you could process the api response in `user.login(..).then(...)`. The purpose of my answer was to alert you on the `this` problem.